# creating a team of players from a list

Tags: java, linked-list

Hey im trying to create a random way to pick a team of 4 from a linkedlist and am wondering if this code will work.

heres an example code

```
 public static void enterGame(Client c) {
    int n = teamSize;
    boolean startNewGame = false;
    if(waitingPlayers.size() <= 3) {
        return; // not enough players
    }
    startNewGame = true;
    if(startNewGame) {
        System.out.println("Starting new game");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            Collections.shuffle(waitingPlayers);
            System.out.println("Picking random player");
            waitingPlayers.remove(c);
            System.out.println("removing from random player list");
            players.add(c);
            System.out.println("adding player to ingame list");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from posting your code elsewhere in the future. Also, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) and a sublist. In order to know if your code works why don't you test it (unit test or just some try)?

Also, this part:

```
boolean startNewGame = false;
if(waitingPlayers.size() > 3) {
        startNewGame = true;
} else {
        startNewGame = false;
        return;
}
if(startNewGame) {
```

is over complicated, I would replace it by:

```
if(waitingPlayers.size() <= 3) {
    return; // not enough players
}
```

Full code:

```
public static void enterGame(final Client c) {      
    if(waitingPlayers.size() <= 3) {
        return; // not enough players
    }

    System.out.println("Starting new game");
    Collections.shuffle(waitingPlayers);
    System.out.println("Picking random players");
    // ? to be replaced by the real type of objects inside waitingPlayers
    final List<?> picked = waitingPlayers.subList(0, 3); 
    players.addAll(picked);
    waitingPlayers.removeAll(picked);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by a sublist.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug - you are picking a number from 0 to n. If n is selected, you will get an out of bounds exception. Other fhan that it seems fine.